# Limit with fraction in numerator

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit for 
$$
\lim_{x\,\rightarrow\,0} \frac {\frac{1}{x+3} - \frac{1}{3}}{x}
$$

It's supposed to be $-1/9$. I've tried changing it around multiple ways, and get the $9$ but never the $1$ over neg $9$.

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the fractions in the numerator? You know, common denominator and all that?

Comment: I did and got [-x]/[3(x+3)]. Is that right  at that point or did I mess something up there?

Comment: That's right. That's the numerator. So now divide the numerator by $x$...

Comment: Simplify first getting $\frac{-1}{3(x+3)}$ then plug in $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x+3} - \frac{1}{3}}{x} =
  \frac{3 - (x+3)}{3x\,(x+3)} =
  \frac{-x}{3x\,(x+3)} =
  \frac{-1}{3(x+3)}
$$

And you can continue from there.

Answer (score 1):

The solution presented by @wltrup is solid and efficient.  I thought that it would be instructive to present another way forward.

Here, straightforward application of L'Hospital's Rule reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac13}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{1}{(x+3)^2}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac19
\end{align}$$

as expected!